# If con $_SESSION

Tags: php, condiciones

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["TIP"])){
    header("location:../index.php?msg=1");
}else if(isset($_SESSION["TIP"])){
    if($_SESSION["TIP"]!="Normal"){
        header("location:../index.php?msg=3");  
    }else if ($_SESSION["TIP"]!="Gold") {
        header("location:../index.php?msg=3");                  
    }
}
```

Tengo este código para validar si el usuario que entra al programa tiene los permisos correspondientes, el problema es que mi variable `$_SESSION["TIP"]` si es igual a "Normal" pero me la toma como si no lo fuera.

Esto solo pasa cuando pongo el `else if` o unos `||` en la condición, alguien sabe donde esta mi error?

Comment: Trata de mejorar la forma en la que implementas las condiciones ya que se puede hacer mucho más simple. Primero haces un if para negar y luego un else para afirmar. Otra cosa también es el hecho de que cuando veríficas si tu variable de sesión es distinto a "normal" se puede dar el caso de que normal != gold y ni siquiera tomaría el siguiente else if.

Comment: Hola, podrías mejorar la edición para aclarar mejor la duda, cuando dices que la condición es si es igual a "Normal" pero veo que estás haciendo lo contrario; es decir si no es igual a "Normal".

Answer (score 1):

bueno al punto, dices que $_SESSION["TIP"] si es igual a "Normal". Pero nunca le dices que haría si así fuera. Tu código solo tiene comparaciones en caso de que sea distinto a "normal" y a "gold".

Answer (score 0):

### En ningún momento defines la acción que tomaría en caso de que `$_SESSION["TIP"] == "Normal"`.

Una solución sería definirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["TIP"])){
    // Variable de sesión no establecida

} else {
    if( $_SESSION["TIP"] == "Normal" ){
        // Establecida, es Normal

    } else if ( $_SESSION["TIP"] == "Gold") {
        // Establecida, es Gold 

    } else {
        // Establecida, pero no es ninguna de las anteriores

    }
}
```

**Espero que esto sea lo que buscas!!**

Comment: Gracias por responder, ese el es punto, si $_SESSION["TIP"]=="Normal" no quiero que haga nada, que se quede así como está.

Yo solo quiero que se desencadene cuando no sea igual a "Normal"

Comment: Entonces creo que tu error puede estar en que usas en el segundo condicional else, else if en vez de elseif: http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: La solución era más fácil, la condición del if que está dentro del if(isset($_SESSION["TIP"])) tenía que ser: $_SESSION["TIP"]!="Normal" && $_SESSION["TIP"]!="Gold"

Tenía que ser con && no con ||

Answer (score 0):

La solución era más fácil de lo que parecía:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["TIP"])){
    header("location:../index.php?msg=1");
}else if(isset($_SESSION["TIP"])){
    if($_SESSION["TIP"]!="Normal" && $_SESSION["TIP"]!="Gold"){
        header("location:../index.php?msg=3");
    }               
}
```

Solo tuve que cambiar los || por &&

Comment: y por que cambiarlos, antes era alguna de las dos opciones y ahora pides que ambas condiciones se cumplan?

Comment: había puesto al inicio que pasaba con los if o si ponía un || en la condición

Answer (score 0):

es ta simple como:

```
$session = $_SESSION["TIP"] ?? false;
if(!$session){
   header("location:../index.php?msg=3"); 
}

if ($session != "Gold" || $session != "Normal" ) {
   header("location:../index.php?msg=3");                  
}



// continuamos ejecucion normal  porque es gold o normal
```

Comment: Por favor agrega una descripción a tu respuesta.

Comment: ¿Y eso que hace?